# Ошибка is not a function

Tags: javascript

Выдаёт ошибку: app.configure is not a function.

в чём может быть проблема: Подскажите пожалуйста

```html
var express  = require('express'),
    Recaptcha = require('recaptcha').Recaptcha;

var PUBLIC_KEY  = '6LdtyzoUAAAAAFCPtAGGPlzjQC7pz7e2bFB1AHZj',
    PRIVATE_KEY = '6LdtyzoUAAAAAN4aT1j5I3-x6kEaWuXkP2SgTs0G';

var app = express();

app.configure(function() {
    app.use(express.bodyParser());
});

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    var recaptcha = new Recaptcha(PUBLIC_KEY, PRIVATE_KEY);

    res.render('form.jade', {
        layout: false,
        locals: {
            recaptcha_form: recaptcha.toHTML()
        }
    });
});

app.post('/', function(req, res) {
    var data = {
        remoteip:  req.connection.remoteAddress,
        response:  req.body['g-recaptcha-response']
    };
    var recaptcha = new Recaptcha(PUBLIC_KEY, PRIVATE_KEY, data);

    recaptcha.verify(function(success, error_code) {
        if (success) {
            res.send('Recaptcha response valid.');
        }
        else {
            // Redisplay the form.
            res.render('form.jade', {
                layout: false,
                locals: {
                    recaptcha_form: recaptcha.toHTML()
                }
            });
        }
    });
});

app.listen(3000);
```

Comment: проект node js.

Answer (score 4):

[Важные изменения, внесенные в версии Express 4:](http://expressjs.com/ru/guide/migrating-4.html)

> Функция app.configure() удалена. Для определения среды и
>   соответствующей настройки приложения используйте process.env.NODE_ENV
>   или функцию app.get('env').